# Obtener datos de un web services PHP

Tags: php, json, array, webservice

Se me facilito un web services, donde el link me retorna información, supongamos que es este link:

> http://web/fin/0123456789

el caso, es que me retorna información con esta estructura:

```
{"dato1":"0123456789",
   "datos_juntos":[{
      "uno":"1",
      "dos":"2"},
   "datos_juntos":{
      "uno":"3",
      "dos":"4"}]}
```

Para obtener el `"dato1"` no tengo ningún problema. 
El problema es los `"datos_juntos"`, ya que es un array.
Tengo el siguiente condigo:

```
$data = json_decode( file_get_contents('http://web/fin/0123456789'), true );
foreach($data as $user){
   echo "* ".$user."</br>";     
}
```

al ejecutar esto me da lo siguiente:

```
*0123456789
                   Error
                   Array to string conversion
* Array
```

Lo unico que se hacer es contarlos:

```
echo count($data['datos_juntos']); ==> 2
```

Me gustaria saber como puedo leer esos datos que vienen en array desde el web services, es la primera vez que manejo datos de este estilo.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

me dieron ideas y así me funciono:

```
$data=file_get_contents("http://web/fin/0123456789");
$products = json_decode($data, true);


    $cont=count($products['datos_juntos']);


    foreach($products as $key => $val) {
        if($key!="datos_juntos"){
            echo "<b>$key: </b>$val</br>";
        }else{
            echo "$key: </br>";
            for($i=0;$i<$cont;$i++){
                foreach($products['datos_juntos'][$i] as $keys => $val1) {
                    echo "<b>$keys:</b> $val1 <br/>";
                }
                echo "<br>";
            }       
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

estaba validando la estructura del json con esta herramienta,https://jsonlint.com/ , me parece que esta mal formado. 
Esta es la estructura que corregi.

```
    {
    "dato1": "0123456789",
    "datos_juntos": [{
            "uno": "1",
            "dos": "2"
        },
        {
            "uno": "3",
            "dos": "4"
        }
    ]
}



foreach ($data['datos_juntos'] as $key => $value) {
            echo "{$key} : {$value}";
        }
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Puedes agregar en la respuesta lo que cambiaste o lo que estaba mal? Así las otras personas que lean tu respuesta van a comprender mejor.

Answer (score 0):

probaste con meter el array en un for?
Algo como:

```
$cant=count($data['datos_juntos']);
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $Cant - 1; $i++) {
        $dato=$data[datos_juntos][$i];
  echo $dato;
  }
```